# Is Salesforce endpoint version the same globally?

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce offers an endpoint to know [which version is available](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_versions.htm) but doesn't mention if the latest version is available globally or locally, on the requested instance.

For example, the latest version on `eu6` is **37** but is it the same globally and can I use the version 37 by hard coding it in my code or everytime a new customer create an account, I need to store the latest version available for his instance region ?

Answer (score 1):

The version endpoint is not global it only applies to the one instance you asked on (eu6 in your example). You should build an integration against a specific version. Worst case latest version -1 is available everywhere, so you could build an integration once today against v36 and it will work for all users of salesforce.